# no hdmi sound, first time installing linux

Tags: hdmi

On the profile all the hdmi outputs have (unplugged) (unavailable)
Ubuntu Studio

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-25-lowlatency
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Memory: 13.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe

First there was no image, after searching I found that nomodeset in grub helps, done.

Second: I have vídeo but no audio, i try differents suggestions but I dont get working hdmi sound. Thanks in advance.

The motherboard it's an asus prime a320m-k.

Answer (score 0):

I re install ubuntu from live usb using nomodeset in grub configuration (becouse without nomodeset I had to boot with recovery mode "I had black screen with the normal boot"), after installation it's working great...!! thanks in advance.